# Defining a generic class which implements a generic interface

Tags: java, generics

I have requirement where I want to define a `generic class` which implements a `generic interface`.

This is my custom map interface:

```
public interface ICache<K, T> {
     boolean containsKey(K k);
     T getValue (K key);
     void remove(K key);
     void put(K k, T t);
}
```

This is the custom class implementation:

```
 public class CustomCache<K, T> implements ICache<K, T> {

    private org.infinispan.Cache<K, T> cache;

    public CustomCache(org.infinispan.Cache<K, T> cache) {
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(K k) {
        return cache.containsKey(k);
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue(K key) {
        return cache.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(K key) {
        cache.remove(key);
    }

   @Override
   public void put(K k, T t) {
       cache.put(k, t);
   }
}
```

But when I try to construct a Cache, I get warnings like "Cache is a raw type. References to generic type Cache should be parameterized"...

A sample method to create a custom map.

```
public ICache<?, ?> lookupCache(String cacheName) {
    ICache<?, ?> cache = null;
    Cache<?, ?> jCache = new DefaultCacheManager().getCache();
    cache = new CustomCache(jCache);
    return cache;
}
```

One way to avoid this is simply use, @SuppressWarnings, but can I fix the same using generic.

Using the <> operator though fixes this, **but I need to make it 1.6 compatible too.**

Comment: Note: In Java the convention is to not use the "I"-prefix for interface names. (AFAIK this convention comes from the C-world.)

Comment: Am already working on the refactoring part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning pretty much sums it up: your class `Cache` is a generic type, meaning it takes type parameters, but your reference to the `Cache` object called `jCache` doesn't have such type parameters. You should not only supply them in the declaration, but also in the initialization, like so:

```
cache = new CustomCache<Object, Object>(jCache);
```

It basically says that you have an object of class `CustomCache` but you don't know the `K` nor the `T` type (yet). All you can say at this point is you'll put only `Object`s in it.

Comment: So if I use this, then the have a look at the sample method for creating custom map, then the method signature should look like: public ICache<? extends Object, ? extends Object> lookupCache(String cacheName);

Comment: The `?` wildcard means an unknown type; see the [Java tutorial on generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html).

Comment: If you use `?`, you don't have to add `extends Object`, because _any_ type extends `Object`, so it doesn't matter you don't know the type, it will always extend `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

I would implemented it as

```
public class Cache<K, T> implements ICache<K, T> {
    Map<K, T> map = new HashMap<K, T>();

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(K k) {
        return map.containsKey(k);
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue(K key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(K key) {
        map.remove(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void put(K k, T t) {
        map.put(k, t);
    }
}
```

it as Adapter pattern

Comment: If you look at my solution its almost the same, but the difference is here you are defining a new HashMap, which I can't do because, my inner map is being looked from some other source (here JBOSS container). That's why I added a constructor, and that's where the trouble is. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without trying, I think you can solve situations like this using a generic helper method:

```
private <K, T> ICache<K, T> createCache)(org.infinispan.Cache<K, T> cache){
  return new CustomCache<K, T>(cache);
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. But would be more interested in understanding why had to resort to a helper method.

Comment: generic helper methods can help in some situations to relate generic type parameters (e.g. type parameters of input and output or of 2 input arguments) without knowing their actual type (e.g. "?")

Comment: E.g. in this case you say "whatever the type paramters of the input are, I want the same type paramters for the output", which is different from "?" = "unknown type paramter".

Comment: Now that's what got mixed up, I mistook the meaning of ? here.